# How to keep session alive when using async websockets?

Tags: python, session, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I have this code to interact with a websocket api using `async` and `websokets` python libraries:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, json
import asyncio
from websockets import connect

class AsyncWebsocket():
    async def __aenter__(self):
        self._conn = connect('wss://ws.myws.com/v2')
        self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()        
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        await self._conn.__aexit__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def send(self, message):
        await self.websocket.send(message)

    async def receive(self):
        return await self.websocket.recv()

class mtest():
    def __init__(self, api_token):
        self.aws        = AsyncWebsocket()
        self.loop       = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.api_token  = api_token

        self.authorize()

    def authorize(self):
        jdata = self.__async_exec({
                                    'authorize': self.api_token
                                  })

        try:
            print (jdata['email'])
            ret = True
        except:
            ret = False

        return ret

    def sendtest(self):

        jdata = self.__async_exec({
                                    "hello": 1
                                  })

        print (jdata)


    def __async_exec(self, jdata):
        try:
            ret = json.loads(self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__async_send_recieve(jdata)))
        except:
            ret = None

        return ret

    async def __async_send_recieve(self, jdata):
        async with self.aws:
            await self.aws.send(json.dumps(jdata))
            return await self.aws.receive()
```

So I have the following in main.py:

```
from webclass import *

a = mtest('12341234')
print (a.sendtest())
```

The problem is that it doesn't preserve the authorized session, so this is the output:

```
root@ubupc1:/home/dinocob# python3 test.py 
asd@gmail.com
{'error': {'message': 'Please log in.', 'code': 'AuthorizationRequired'}}
```

As you see, the login call are working ok, but when calling and sending the `hello` in `sendtest` function, the session is not the same.

- Where is destroyed the session?
- How could I preserve it (without drastically
  modifying my class structure)?

Comment: Where are you saving your authorized token once you logged in ?

Comment: Into `self.api_token` inside `__init__` function. But it works ok; the problem appears when calling `__async_send_recieve` function I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue might be in the context_manager or the `with` [statement.](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

```
async def __async_send_recieve(self, jdata):
    async with self.aws:
        await self.aws.send(json.dumps(jdata))
        return await self.aws.receive()
```

When you invoke 'with' the context should play out as following (with better exception handling and all the benefits of context managers, so you can picture the flow of `__async_send_recieve` as:

```
       self.aws.__aenter__()
       self.aws.send(data)
       self.aws.receive()
       self.aws.__aexit__()
```

To prove this theory, add a print statement into the `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` functions, and you should be able to better visualize the context manager flow.

The fix would be to re-authorize in every request. But I imagine what you want to do is have your test class to manage the context used to communicate with the remote server. (my async syntax might be a little wrong here, but conceptually with context managers):

```
class Mtest():
    def __init__(self, ...):
           ...

    def __enter__(self,):
        self.authorize()

    def __exit__(self):
        self.deauthorize()

    async def make_async_request(self, data):
        await self.aws.send(json.dumps(data))
        return await self.aws.receive()

with Mtest(api_key) as m:
    m.make_async_request({'test_data': 'dummy_test_data'})
    m.make_async_request({'more_data': 'more_mock_data'})
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, seems the server remember the login status for each websocket connection, so you don't need to do anything on client side.

> Where is destroyed the session?

The session is destroyed on server side.

> How could I preserve it?

Fix the server bug?